# How to get the node data, inside the template in GOJS?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I want to create a few textBlock only if the text in the data equals to specific string.
if not - I want to create only one textBlock.

```
var template = GO(go.Node, "Auto",{desiredSize: new go.Size(width, height) },     
                  GO(go.Shape, shapeMap.getValue(shape), new go.Binding("fill", "fill")),  
                  ( ???? .includes("[UMS]")) ?
                        GO(go.Panel, "Vertical",
                            GO(go.TextBlock,{font: "7pt serif"}, new go.Binding("stroke", "color"), new go.Binding("text", "txtPart1")),
                            GO(go.TextBlock,{text: "[UMS]", font: "7pt serif", click: function(e, obj) {window.open("https://" + obj.part.data.key + ":8090")}}, new go.Binding("stroke", "color")),
                            GO(go.TextBlock,{font: "7pt serif"}, new go.Binding("stroke", "color"), new go.Binding("text", "txtPart2")))
                        :
                           GO(go.TextBlock,{font: "7pt serif"}, new go.Binding("stroke", "color"), new go.Binding("text", "txtPart1"))

                       );
```

How to test on the data.text if it's include or not?

(I know how to get it inside function:click: function(e, obj) {return obj.part.data.key }

or how to declare it - using Binding - so the data will be per node and not per template.
but in the code inside the template??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a data-binding that bind's a `TextBlock`'s or `Panel`'s visibility to the data.text. Here's one such example:

```
      new go.Binding("visible", "text", function(textvalue) {
        return (textvalue.indexOf("[UMS]") >= 0);
      })
```

In that example, if the text does not contain `"[UMS]"`, the GraphObject that has this binding will be invisible (It won't be shown and it won't take up space).

Here's a full example: http://codepen.io/simonsarris/pen/jPzyoa?editors=001

Whole template for posterity:

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
  $(go.Node, "Vertical",
    new go.Binding('background', 'color'),
    $(go.TextBlock,
      { margin: 3 },
      new go.Binding("text", "key")),
    // This textblock will be hidden if the data.text does not contain "three"
    $(go.TextBlock,
      { margin: 3 },
      new go.Binding("text", "text"),
      new go.Binding("visible", "text", function(textvalue) {
        return (textvalue.indexOf('three') >= 0);
      })
     )
  );
```

You can read more about data-binding and conversion functions here: http://gojs.net/latest/intro/dataBinding.html

Comment: I tried use the function inside the binding,
but I didn't have the idea to use it in the visible property.
cool & great. tnx.